# Calculate the probability for numbered balls of different colours

Tags: probability

> A box contains 40 numbered red balls and 60 numbered black balls. From the box the balls are drawn one by one at random without replacement till all the balls are drawn. The probability that the last ball drawn is black equals what?

Can someone give a bit of elaboration on this: On listing its sample space $S$ and event points as follows: $$S=\{R_1,R_2, \ldots, R_{40},B_1,B_2,\ldots, B_{60}\}$$
While if $E$ denotes the event, then: $$E=\{B_1,B_2, \ldots,B_{60}\}$$
And accordingly the probability should be ${60\over 100}=3/5.$ I suppose that solves the question correctly, doesn't it? Or am I skipping some vital explanation to why it goes  this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  Since each ball is equally likely to be selected last and $60$ of the $100$ available balls are black, the probability that a black ball is selected last is 
$$p = \frac{60}{100} = \frac{3}{5}$$